# How to use regular expression in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have tried this code..

```
<script>
  angular.module('emailExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.text = 'me@example.com';
    }]);
</script>
  <form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
    Email: <input type="email" name="input" ng-model="text" required>
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">
      Required!</span>
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.email">
      Not valid email!</span>
    <tt>text = {{text}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>myForm.input.$valid = {{myForm.input.$valid}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>myForm.input.$error = {{myForm.input.$error}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>myForm.$error.required = {{!!myForm.$error.required}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>myForm.$error.email = {{!!myForm.$error.email}}</tt><br/>
  </form>
```

But getting issue in validation. Say if i try to enter 'a@a.c' in email then it will not show any error. Please help me on this.

Comment: That is correct as per angular email validation..use ng-pattern for making it more precise

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am thinking why you are not using `ng-pattern` for this. You can make a regular expression and put inside `ng-pattern.`

Example:

```
<form name="signupFrm">

    <input type="email", ng-pattern="emailPattern">

</form>
```

or,

HTML:

```
    <div ng-class="{'has-error': signupFrm.email.$dirty && signupFrm.email.$invalid}">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" ng-pattern="emailPattern" required="required">
        <div ng-show="signupFrm.email.$dirty && signupFrm.email.$invalid || signupFrm.email.$error.pattern">
           <span ng-show="signupFrm.email.$error.pattern && signupFrm.email.$invalid " class="help-block"> should look like an email address</span>
           <span ng-show=" signupFrm.email.$error.required" class="help-block">can't be blank</span>
       </div> 
  </div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.emailPattern = /^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.(([a-zA-Z]){2,6})$/;
```

Comment: I have tried this but didn't work <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ang.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Ctrl($scope) {
        $scope.text = 'enter email';
        $scope.word = /^[a-z]+[a-z0-9._]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z.]{2,5}$/;
    }
</script>
    </head>
<body>
    <form name="myform" ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <input type="text" ng-pattern="word" name="email">
        <span class="error" ng-show="myform.email.$error.pattern">
            invalid email!
        </span>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>