# How to use Regex expression to modify my variable value?

Tags: regex, typescript, angular6

I have a variable `rawvalue`:

```
let rawvalue = {abc-def-qwe}
```

I want to use regex to remove the <kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>}</kbd>; I can simply do this by truncating the first and last characters. I built the regex:

```
^.(.*.).$
```

I want to know how to apply this regex on my variable to get the desired output?

Comment: Try `string.replace(/{([^{}]*)}/g,"\1")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you're looking for is like this:

```
let input = "{abc-def-qwe}";
let re = /^.(.*.).$/;
let fixed = re.exec(input)[1];   // Get the first match group "abc-def-qwe"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, [this RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/3t6kIy/1) might be a better choice, which creates one group and you can simply call it using <kbd>$1</kbd> and replace your string:

```
^\{(.+)\}$
```

[image]

For implementation, you might use, maybe these posts: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51741573/angular-reactive-forms-pattern-validator-adding-to-regex-and-breaking-validati), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51046044/angular-pattern-validation-with-regex), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27664798/6553328).

Comment: Thanks for this, but my question is more focused on how to use the regex in my code? I am not sure of the format as to how to actually format my string using this regex? 

Something like: var abc = new RegExp(..,..)